# Set Visual Studio Code settings.json across workspace regardless of the opened subfolder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

If `.vscode/settings.json` is included in the root of a project, and one opens up the project from the root folder, the settings are applied. However, if one opens up a folder within the project, such as `project/frontend`, the settings aren't applied unless a `.vscode/settings.json` is included within the `frontend` folder as well. Is there any way to keep one settings file that applies to the whole workspace, regardless of which subfolder (any depth) is opened?

- I've tried adding a .code-workspace file, and including the settings in there, but that doesn't seem to have any effect. I tried the suggestions in this question: [Visual Studio Code and subfolder-specific settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47405315/visual-studio-code-and-subfolder-specific-settings) but they didn't achieve the desired effect.
- Keeping the settings as user settings is an easy solution, but the settings need to be shared with other developers which is why a `.vscode/settings.json` is necessary. I'd prefer to maintain one.
- The usefulness of having settings for each level of the folder is evident, since `project/frontend` may have different settings than `project/backend`, but the settings in those should extend the root settings rather than replace.
- [How to apply VSCode workspace settings to all subfolders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69919821/how-to-apply-vscode-workspace-settings-to-all-subfolders) was also asked but it didn't seem there were any answers there.